# MS Access - run report from a form that has 2 buttons that use the same report but have different results

Tags: vba, ms-access

We would like to run a form that will have 2 buttons that use the same report but have different results:

Button 1 - open report for current record (which we have working) using

```vb
Private Sub Command25_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Bale Spike Certificate", acViewPreview, , "[no] = " & Me.[no]
End Sub
```

Button 2 - open (Bale Spike Certificate) report (same report that button 1 points to) but when it opens it requests the user to enter the serial number [no] which will show the report of the entered serial number.

Can get the report to work off a query by using a criteria on the [no] field, but when I change the report to use the query as the record source, button 1 (current record print) stops working and the other way round, if I use DoCmd for the current record.

Is there a way of achieving this? Or do I create 2 reports for each button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an *InputBox*:

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click()

    Dim SerialNo   As Long

    SerialNo = Val(InputBox("Enter Serial No.:", "Bale Spike Certificate"))
    If SerialNo > 0 Then
        DoCmd.OpenReport "Bale Spike Certificate", acViewPreview, , "[no] = " & SerialNo & ""
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Spot on, works a treat

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered.